# How to enable Mongojs Safe Option?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Consider the following nodejs code:

```
db = require('mongojs')('database', ['users, sessions']);
db.users.insert(
{
  'email': email,
  'password': password,
  'firstname': firstname,
  'lastname': lastname
}, 
function(err) {
  // will there ever be output?     
});
```

In this case, is safe mode enabled for mongodb to output error? If not, how do I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enabled automatically in Mongojs, if you specify a callback.

https://github.com/gett/mongojs/blob/master/index.js#L168